# Accessing abstract class method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have three different classes:

1-)

```
abstract class A {
abstract void one();
void two(){
    System.out.println("two");
one();
}
abstract void three();
 }
```

2-)

```
abstract class B extends A {
void one() {
    System.out.println("one");
    three();//I think this method has to run
}

void three() {
    System.out.println("3");//That
}
}
```

3-)

```
public class C extends B {
void three(){
    System.out.println("three");
}

}
```

in the Main method

```
public static void main(String [] args){
C c=new C();
c.one();
c.two();
c.three();
}
```

Output :

```
one
three
two
one
three
three
```

But I think in second code one() method have to run its three method and it has to show "3" instead of "three" but this code runs three in C class.

Answer (score 1):

three() method is overridden both in B and C class

Since c is an instance of C class, any reference to three() method with c object will invoke the three() implementation in C class

Answer (score 1):

The `three()` method is overridden in `C`. Since `c` holds an instance of `C`, that's the output you see.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding in java always works based on the target object in reference ‘c’. So firstly it will look up in C class for any available overridden version of three()  method, otherwise, subsequent parent class version will get executed.